# Merge sort recursion call stack

Tags: sorting, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to understand how merge sort recursion stack actually manages to merge two arrays into a sorted array.

The code and the output are at - https://gist.github.com/antani/144a2dfc85d89ae86297 (to prevent clutter in the question)

I am not able to visualize the stack trace of this algorithm

Comment: The **merging** isn't done by the recursive calls. Instead, it's done by that perfectly ordinary `while` loop.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Have a look at the animated image on the right here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort and you should get how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, both arrays `left` and `right` are sorted if they will be merged. Then the algorithm compares the first and therefore the smallest `left`-value with the smallest `right`-value. The smaller value of both is the next value for the resulting array.

After this part the resulting array is also sorted and will be returned back to the recursion depth/step/iteration `n -1`...

Maybe this animated working sort algorithms will hell you to understand: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com